# What is "Advanced tool site" in Azure Web App Access Restrictions?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-security

When I restrict access to my Azure Web App in the "Access Restrictions" page of the portal, besides "Main site" there is another tab called "Advanced tool site". What is that?

This term is not mentioned anywhere else. Should I disable access to that part also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far I understand, you are trying to understand the purpose of ***Advanced tool site*** in ***Azure App Service->Networking***.

[image]

This option is for ***Restricting access to the SCM site/KUDU site*** which is used for managing and also for troubleshooting the web application.

Whatever the way (Using IDE's deployment, DevOps Pipelines deployment, Command-line deployment/Publishing) you have deployed your Web App or Web Jobs or Mobile App to an App Service, ***You can see the deployed files in the Kudu Site to know how it is deployed, any missing dependency files or assembly files, etc***.

**KUDU/SCM site:**

To access your KUDU site: Go to App Service->Search for Advanced Tools->click on `Go->` .

[image]

**Restrict the access to SCM:**

- You can add new rules and assign to restrict the access to SCM site separately by adding the rules in *Advanced tool suite->Add*.

[image]

- To use the same restrictions for both application and the SCM site, select "Use main site rules" under *Advanced tool suite.* It will apply the same rules from the *Main Site*.

[image]

**References:**
[MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions?tabs=azurecli#restrict-access-to-an-scm-site)